# using linq to get a single record from a table linked to another table

Tags: c#, linq

The question is confusing since I really didn't know how to ask this.

Anyhow, I have 4 tables and I need to get to the TokenSetting table to get a single record.  I am given the companycode and I have to travel from there and get the rest of the information that I need. And because there are multiple corporationstructures to each corporation I have to get the corporationstructure first to get the tokens assigned to it.

Here is the layout:

[image]

This is my code:

```
  _currentcorp = (from c in _entities.Corporations
              where c.CompanyCode == textBox_CompanyCode.Text
              select c).FirstOrDefault();

  if (_currentcorp == null)
  {
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox_CompanyCode, "Invalid corporation.");
    return;
  }

  var corpstructure = (from cs in _currentcorp.CorporationStructures
                          where cs.District == null &&
                                cs.Branch == null &&
                                cs.Region == null
                          select cs).FirstOrDefault();

  if (corpstructure == null)
  {
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox_CompanyCode, "Invalid corporation structure.");
    return;
  }

  var tokensetting = (from ts in _currentcorp.Tokens
                      where ts.CorporationStructureId == corpstructure.CorporationStructureId                           
                      select ts.TokenSettings).FirstOrDefault();
```

tokensetting is coming back as ienumerable even though I'm telling it to get firstordefault. I'm assuming that it's saying get firstordefault on the tokens?

Anyhow, there should only be 1 record in the tokensetting table even though the table is 1 to many. How do I return the firstordefault only on this table?

**==== ANSWER ====**

As suggested, I did the following:

```
  var tokensetting = (from ts in _currentcorp.Tokens
                      where ts.CorporationStructureId == corpstructure.CorporationStructureId                           
                      select ts.TokenSettings.FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Did you try to log the executed SQL statements and then executed them manually? Is there really only 1 token setting row for given criteria?

Comment: yes there is though my issue is really that the tokensetting is evaluated as being ienumberable. That means I'm not returning the desired results of a single record but instead a collection.

Comment: After all `TokenSettings` is a plural ;) Maybe you want to redesign the table structure and create 1:1 relation between `Token` and `TokenSetting` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the LINQ query is returning a `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerables`, so a second `.FirstOrDefault()` should get you what you want.

The first call specifies that you want the first row in the result of the LINQ query, and the second specifies that you want the first element of `ts.TokenSettings`, which is itself a collection.

Comment: yup simple enough, I tried to put one on it before but outside the () this time I put them inside and it worked! Tyvm!